# In the API, User object, what are all these reputation properties?

Tags: support, api-v2, documentation, reputation

I am going through the JSON that is resulting from calling [the Stack Exchange User API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users).

I see a bunch of reputation fields.

```
private Number reputation;
private Number reputation_change_day;
private Number reputation_change_month;
private Number reputation_change_quarter;
private Number reputation_change_week;
private Number reputation_change_year;
```

What are all these for? Obviously, I know what the reputation is, but the others have me a bit fooled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the reputation that the user has earned for the given period (day/week/month/quarter/year).

For example, for you, for Stack Overflow, [the API currently returns](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=1174024&filter=default&site=stackoverflow):

```js
"reputation_change_day": 0,
"reputation_change_week": 0,
"reputation_change_month": 32,
"reputation_change_quarter": 63,
"reputation_change_year": 111,
```

This should jibe with what you currently see on your ["multi-super-whatever-you-call-them drop down"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/83735/148310).

It matches what we see on [the *Users* page, reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=quarter&search=nicholas%20dipiazza):

[image: Reputation by period filter]

And what we see in [the Reputation Leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow) :

[image: Reputation Leagues]

Comment: You're welcome.  Lot's of stuff is obvious in hindsight, but there are no bad questions! (Well, except for the ones we close all the time. ;) )

Comment: haha yeah there are some bad ones, for sure!